# Correct implementation of Google Tag Manager in OpenCart

Tags: opencart, google-tag-manager

I need some advice in placing Google Tag Manager (assuming the API is already written) in OpenCart. I've thought of loading it straight from header.tpl, however I want to know what the cleanest implementation would be.

Answer (score 0):

I've found this solution to be optimal for me. Tested and it works. You will need Vqmods installed (https://github.com/vqmod/vqmod/wiki).

I used an edited version of this script (http://www.opencart.com/index.php?route=extension/extension/info&extension_id=18200). Basically, what you want to do is replace the search query so that it matches your body tag's class.

Keep in mind that you should check your header.tpl to make sure you place the GTM code right at the beginning of your body tag.

Finally, my edited xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<modification>
<id><![CDATA[Google Tag Manager]]></id>
    <version><![CDATA[1.0]]></version>
    <vqmver><![CDATA[]]></vqmver>
    <author><![CDATA[hany.mesbah@gadalla.com]]></author>
<file name="catalog/view/theme/*/template/common/header.tpl">
    <operation error="log">
        <search position="after"><![CDATA[<body class="fs<?php echo $themeConfig['fontsize'];?> <?php echo $helper->getPageClass();?> <?php echo $helper->getParam('body_pattern','');?>">]]></search> 
            <add><![CDATA[your GTM code snippet]]></add>
    </operation>        
</file>
</modification>
```